# How to make navbar responsive

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I believe it is not responsive because I added navbar-fixed-top instead of what bootstrap uses, which is navbar navbar-default. Would you know how to make it responsive while the navbar is fixed?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

Comment: Bootstrap 3 is already fully responsive across all devices.

Comment: Hm. For some reason it's not responsive...

Comment: Then you are missing something make sure you have this in the head of you pages. change the paths as needed <link href="styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

Comment: It's there. I added the navbar code above.

Comment: what is  class="toggle-transparent tof"

Comment: It's an overlay that I added when you hit on Table of Contents.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me
Here is an example of what it should look like.

```
 <head>
 <link href="styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
 <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 </head>

       <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="">  </a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Book</a></li>
           <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span> Table of Contents</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">content 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">content 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">content 3</a></li>

            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </div>
```

you can also see many examples of working navbars on the bootstrap site

[Bootstrap examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples)

Comment: I believe it is not responsive because the navbar is fixed. Look above. Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: navbar-fixed-top is used by bootstrap and is responsive. I would recommend you delete your navbar and use one of bootstraps examples. after you have one of those working try to edit it to your liking.